# Should image binaries be stored as BLOBS in a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, blob

If an application requires images (ie. JPGs, PNGs etc) to be referenced in a database-driven application, should these images just be stored in a file system with their path referenced in a database, or should the images actually be stored in the database as BLOBS?

Comment: You like starting holy wars, don't you?

Comment: "And yay, they came unto us with their BLOB data, and we did smiteth them with relative file paths. But then lo, the absolutists came and did cause much wailing and gnashing of teeth."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: -1 for no basic research first which would have found answers already on DBA.SE and SO

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise there were so many questions already on this.  I don't mind if this is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database VARBINARY column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's FILESTREAM attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee foto in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee foto, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it "LARGE_DATA".

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store VARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX) columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
     (....... define the fields here ......)
     ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
     TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!

Comment: +1 large `blob` data isn't actually stored in row though so the benefit of partitioning into another table might not be all that great.

Comment: @MartinSmith: true - but it will prevent an accidental `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable.....` to return oodles of blobs....

Comment: My view is the decision comes down to "do you want full ACID and data integrity?". http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2445/630

Comment: Why would having a Blob in your Employee table slow down queries to it?

Comment: So, let me get this straight: oodles of blobs = bad; oodles of noodles = good;?

Comment: @CraigJohnston BLOB fields are not stored inline with the rest of the row's data. So doing a `SELECT * FROM Employees` would require loading the regular fields inline, and then having to go to a separate place to grab the BLOB field. It's generally best to try to retrieve BLOB data separate from the rest of the row's fields, if possible.